# How to run django files in another virtualenv environment on another server?

Tags: python, django, server, virtualenv

I am in the process of moving a site created in django to another server. I have packed all files into a zip package, created a new virtualenv environment on a second server, and dumpdate into a .json file. I already have all the files on the destination server, but unfortunately I don't know what to do next.

How to run django in the new virtualenv environment? Should I extract the files to a folder with the new virtualenv? If so, do I have to activate virtualenv first?

I will also add that migration takes place from two different systems. From windows on ubuntu.

Comment: Where your project is located has nothing to do with the virtualenv. You need to activate the new virtualenv (making sure you've installed all the packages required by your project), then just `cd` into your project folder and run `runserver` as you're used to to check everything is working. Not sure though if you're talking about a "production" server or just another development server.

Comment: We are talking about server development. I installed a new virtualenv environment, uploaded dependencies from the requirements.txt file, but how do I transfer project files to the new environment? Should I just copy the entire project folder to the new virtualenv?

Comment: "copy the entire project folder to the new virtualenv" does not make sense. As I said in my comment, your project folder can be anywhere. Didn't I say "just `cd` into your project folder" and then you can do `python manage.py runserver` (or any other `manage.py` command). As long as you've activated your virtualenv.

Comment: That's right, you wrote it, but after installing all dependencies, I don't have a folder with the manage.py file, I don't have any django files at all, and even more so the project folder ...

Comment: But that's in your project (you said you zipped it and copied it to the new server and I suppose unzipped it somewhere).

Comment: As I wrote. I packed the file and I was counting on further help, because really my knowledge in the field of django is marginal. I didn't unpack it anywhere, because I don't even know where to make it correct.

Comment: unpack it anywhere you like. It doesn't matter where.

Comment: After several unsuccessful attempts, I have one more question. Should I prepare an empty django instance on the second target server in addition to preparing the new virtualenv?

Comment: What do you mean by “empty django instance”?

Comment: Default django installation ... But I install it with the command `pip freeze -r requirements.txt`.

Comment: No you install your packages with pip install -r requirements.txt not with pip freeze. And that only installs django (and other required packages). Still don’t know what you mean by empty django instance. Check if your virtualenv is correctly installed: after activating it, python -m django —version should print the django version.

Comment: Django is installed correctly, virtualenvs too. I imported a database, configured wsgi apache, but as a result I get a blank page.

Comment: Does `manage.py runserver` work? Does `manage.py shell` work and can you retrieve model instances in the shell? You could even `curl -v http://127.0.0.1:8000/` to check what your runserver returns. That'll validate that your project works. Then you should check your apache logs. Blank page isn't a bad sign, at least it's returning a HTTP 200 OK. Anyway this is a different question, try to nail down the issue and ask a new question.

Answer (score 4):

1. Save your env packages to a file with a command `pip freeze > requirements.txt`. 
   Afterwards on your new server create virtualenv and install all packages with command `pip install -r requirements.txt`.

Do not copy your virtualenv manually, packages might work differently on another system.

activate your virtualenv and run `python -m django —version` to check that Django is installed correctly.

2. Copy your code repository anywhere you like.
3. Then create your database (empty database) if it’s not SQLite.  `cd` into your project folder. Run `python manage.py migrate` to create the tables of your database.
4. Run `python manage.py loaddata dbdump.data` to migrate all the data of your db. dbdump.data is the file created on the old system with `python manage.py dumpdata`. Note: if the previous project contained data migrations, loaddata will fail because the db will already contain data. In that case you’ll need to manually delete all data in the database first using raw sql.
5. If you had uploaded files on your previous system, copy these files into the MEDIA_ROOT folder (create it if necessary). Check for MEDIA_ROOT in settings.py
6. Run `python manage.py collectstatic`

Now run `manage.py runserver` and check everything works: `curl -v http://127.0.0.1:8000` will show you your project's response.

Comment: Following on this, the `requirements.txt` should be committed to the repository where these files were developed. Presuming the server they will run on has internet access, you would normally clone it, create the virtualenv, then perform the `pip install -r requirement.txt` This allows you to regularly pull new code to the deployed app, and even install new requirements later if necessary.

Comment: OK, I installed all dependencies from the requirements.txt file, but I can't see django files anywhere. If django version 1.11 was required in this file, I understand that it should be automatically installed when executing the command 'pip install -r requirements.txt', right?

Comment: Your django files are installed to your env folder. You have to pull your project additionally from git/svn - i believe you use some kind of code repository. Is your django listed in requirements.txt file ?

Comment: Yes it is listed. In this case, I'm not using a code repository.

Comment: I recommend you using one of the most popular github or gitlab to host your code. The flow is roughly like this: you develop your app localy, when you are finished you push your code to repository, then you go to your server and pull your code, you run migrations / collectstatics and run server. Using scp or rsync to move your code to a server is a bad habit.

Comment: Ok thank you for the advice. I will definitely follow your suggestions when I create a new application. Currently, the case concerns a website that was made by another developer a few years ago. I only have access to files on the old server.

Comment: We're a little bit off the subject. I prepared a new virtualenv environment, installed dependencies from the requirements.txt file and what next?

Comment: Now you have to run migrations on your new database, or restore a backup from old server. And then run your application whether it is using `python manage.py runserver` or gunicorn or uwsgi.

Comment: I can migrate using the `python manage.py loaddata` command directly from a file, e.g. json?

Comment: `python manage.py loaddata` is used to load a dump of your database made with a command `django-admin dumpdata`. So yes, you can load your dump from that file

Comment: Will I also import models, urls etc. in this way? ?

Comment: There are 4 things you need to migrate: your virtualenv, the database, the uploaded files (if any) and your code. The db data can be migrated with loaddata. Your code is just a matter of copying the files anywhere you like (unzipping your zip). Same for the uploaded files (copy them) except you need to make sure to put them in the MEDIA_ROOT directory.

Comment: No you have to import your project from git repository. `loaddata` is only for database data.